# how to render an object with a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I've an object with a list in it, and I want to render them in a `<ul>` format, so when the user add an element to the list, it will add it the render automatic, how do I print the obect `MyData` form inside the Hobbies class

this is the code,

```
var Mydata = {
  name : 'David',
  hobby:[  'diving','traveling','Eating'],
}
```

and this is the my way of rendering it,

```
class Hobbies extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>My hobbies:</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Eat</li>
          <li>Sleep</li>
          <li>Code</li>

        </ul>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the prop hobbies to Hobbies component.

```
// Where you render this: <Hobbies hobbies={Mydata.hobby} />

class Hobbies extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { hobbies } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>My hobbies:</h3>
        <ul>
          {hobbies && hobbies.map(hobby => <li key={hobby}>{hobby}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it gives me this error : Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Because you probably aren't passing the hobbies prop to the component. You can guard against this too.

Comment: after trying to implement ur code, it shows result now, but doesn't print, it doesn't give any error, but not printing

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
return
    (<h3>My hobbies:</h3>
    <ul>
    this.props.level.map((Mydata.hobby, index) => (
        <li>className="indent" key={index}>
            {index}
        </li>
    ))
    </ul>
    );
```

Comment: it says index not define

Comment: return (
        <ul>
          {this.props.list.map(function(Mydata.hobby){
            return <li>{this}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      )

Answer (score 1):

You can use map function to iterate over array and create list as

```
class Hobbies extends React.Component {

  render() {
    var Mydata = {
  name : 'David',
  hobby:[  'diving','traveling','Eating'],
}
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>My hobbies:</h3>
        <ul>
          {Mydata.hobby.map(ele=> <li key={ele.toString()}>{ele}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hobbies />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

alternatively You can store data in state of component and can use as below

```
class Hobbies extends React.Component {
 constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {
    name : 'David',
    hobby:[  'diving','traveling','Eating'],
  }
 }


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>My hobbies:</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.state.hobby.map(ele=> <li key={ele.toString()}>{ele}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hobbies />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And if myData is global object

```
class Hobbies extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>My hobbies:</h3>
        <ul>
          {Mydata.hobby.map(hobby => <li key={hobby}>{hobby}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
var Mydata = {
  name : 'David',
  hobby:[  'diving','traveling','Eating'],
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Hobbies/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: but how can I do it , if the myData is not int he same Hobbies class

Comment: MyData is a global object

Comment: please check last snippet if your myData is global object it can be accessed directly.